# Using EF to fill object list from stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I have the following issue: I need to execute a stored procedure that returns a list of objects, and fill the data with EF. The list has objects A. Object A has object B and C inside. This is why I'm getting an exception.

Any trick to do this?

Code:

```
var result =  _context.Database.SqlQuery<ConciliationSummary>(
           "SP_ConciliationDetail @inputDateFrom = {0}, @inputDateTo = {1}, @inputTrnsNumber = {2}" 
           from, to, trn );

list = result.ToListAsync().Result;
```

I get the exception :

> Cannot create a value for property '' of type ''. Only properties of primitive or enumeration types are supported.

Quite hard to explain the problem in the title, sorry if the title is not accurate

Comment: If this is SQL Server: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thx for the comment. i will take not of that

Comment: It does not seem like SQL Server error. have you tried to pass you string without brackets?: `SP_ConciliationDetail @inputDateFrom = 0, @inputDateTo = 1, @inputTrnsNumber = 2`